# How to import a csv file to the SharePoint list on the fly

Tags: 2010, development

I need to import in the fly day by day a records to a Sharepoint list. At end of a day I need to import a upgrade of vacation users from ending day and add them to the list. How Can I do it. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it pretty easy with PowerShell, check out my post: http://davidlozzi.com/2012/02/29/loading-sharepoint-lists-from-excel/

Comment: And we cant do it in Sharepoint by C# ?

Comment: Yes, didn't see that up there, sorry about that. So from C# you can open the CSV file and read the rows and save it into a list. If you want this automated, you'll want to use a timer job to run it automatically.